# Which tests to run for this interesting study about discrimination?

Tags: regression, interaction

N = ca. 41000

Dependent variable: subjective wellbeing (values from 1 to 10).

Independent variables: job autonomy; income; social trust; political trust;

Moderator: ethnicity (dummmy, 1=yes; 0=no) > N = ca. 2000/41000.

Which test should I use to test these 4 hypotheses?

1-The positive effect of job autonomy on subjective well-being is lower for individuals pertaining to ethnic minorities

2-The positive effect of income....and so on for 3 and 4.

I need an interaction (I suppose job autonomy x ethnicity), but with which test and output do I test my hypotheses?

Struggling since days.

Thank you a lot in advance

Comment: Multiple regression.

Answer (score 0):

Like Jeremy suggested, multiple linear regression can be tried.

$$
Wellbeing = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Job + \beta_2 Ethnicity
$$

If the [linear model is a good fit](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~martin/W2024/R7.pdf), we can then look at the parameters. If $\beta_2$ is statistically significant, the we know it has a positive or negative effect on Wellbeing. There is also a second model that might answer your question better

$$
Wellbeing = \beta_0 + \beta_1 Job + \beta_2 Ethnicity + \beta_3 Job * Ethnicity
$$

This model allows for the effect of ethnicity to change as job autonomy changes.

Comment: Thank you a lot Jeremy and Eric, my doubts faded away. I have run a multiple regression and results are significant for most of the cases. Wish you good luck